# for loop return string 1-30 on the 5th count and 13count from mysql database that matches numbers using php

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I've created a for loop to count 1-30 and want to match mysql number columns 1 - 30 with its attach string data column name and display string inside for loop.

Mysql structure:

```
|-------------|-------------|--------------|
| id          | Number      | Name         |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|
| 90          |  3          | Test Data    |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|
```

tried simular attempts such as:

```
foreach($db->results() as $result) {
  $count = $result->Number;
  $results = $result->Name;
}
for($i=1;$i<=30;$i++) {
  if($count == $i) {
     echo $results;
  }else{
     echo '';
  }
}
```

Needing help! Thank you!!!

================================================================================================================================================================

Ok here is what I am trying to accomplish... It works with assigning to the correct number when matching (Thanks for the suggestion). Here is what I have:

```
$name = array();
$number = array();
foreach($forDB->results() as $for){
   $name = $for->firstname;
   $number = $for->number;
    for($i=1;$i<=30;$i++) {
      if($i<=5){
         if($number == $i) {
            echo $i.' = '.$name;
         }
        } //then the rest of remanding numbers to 30
    }
 }
```

this echos:

2 = name1

4 = name4

But what I would like to do is also echo the numbers of $i between the numbers and values as:

1

2 = name1

3

4 = name4

5

So I try this but it appends to each value:

```
$name = array();
$number = array();
foreach($forDB->results() as $for){
  $name = $for->firstname;
  $number = $for->number;
  for($i=1;$i<=30;$i++) {
     if($i<=5){
        if($number == $i) {
          echo $i.' = '.$name.'<br><br>';
        } else {
          echo $i.'<br>';
        }
     } else {
        echo $i;
     }
   }
 }
```

Results:

2

3

4

5

6

7

1

2 = name2

3

4

5

6

7

1

2

3

4 = Jeff

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Comment: Please show some example output.

Comment: why do you have to loop, why can't you just query to select where `number` equals the number you want it to?

Comment: also you might be meaning to put the for loop inside the foreach loop so that `$count` and `$results` is set each time, right now it just has one set value with the for loop, so it will only meet the if criteria once

Comment: @Michael St Clair he may want only the numbers from 1 to 30, in that case he would have to write 30 ifs to decide if the result number is 1,2,3,4,5,etc. But its really an easy thing to achieve

Comment: It sounds like you need to add a WHERE clause to your query and re-think/simplify your loop.  Hard to tell from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should initialize your count and name variables before the foreach loop as an array then in the foreach loop fill it up with the results, then iterate through it in the for loop.